# $a\mid b$ if and only if $ac \mid bc$ where $c\neq 0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I'm new to number theory so I was wondering if someone could help me with this proof:

$a\mid b$ if and only if $ac \mid bc$ where $c\neq 0$

so far I have:

$b/a=q$ (an integer) $aq=b$
$bc/ac=l$ (an integer) $bc=c(al)$

$bc=aq(c)$ is this right so far? I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 2):

1. $a|b$
2. There is integer $d$, such that $b=ad$
3. There is integer $d$, such that $bc=acd$
4. $(ac)|(bc)$

We have $1\leftrightarrow 2\leftrightarrow 3\leftrightarrow 4$

Comment: for bc=acd...why is d being used again? shouldn't d be replaced with another letter to represent another integer?

Comment: $2\leftrightarrow 3$ by multiplying or dividing by $c$.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to prove an if and only if, which typically translates into proving if (implication) in both directions. In this case, if $a \mid b$ then $a c \mid b c$ when $c \ne 0$; and if $a c \mid bc$ with $c \ne 0$ then $a \mid b$.

Futher, if you don't have any useful facts at hand, unroll definitions. In this case, $a \mid b$ means there is an integer $k$ such that $b = k a$.

I'm sure you can take it from here.

Perhaps you should take a look at [The Book of Proof](http://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/BookOfProof/index.html), it goes over how to prove stuff in quite some detail (and in simple terms, mind you).