# If $a,b,c\neq0$, prove that $ac\mid bc \iff a\mid b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

How can I prove this question?

> If $a,b,c\neq0$, prove that $ac\mid bc \iff a\mid b$

Please help me

Comment: Remember that $a \mid b$ means *a divides b*, that is, by definition, there exists some $r$ such that $b = a \cdot r$. Does this help you understanding what Modded Bear did?

Comment: @Ale oh, thank you so much.I noticed :)

Comment: I have a feeling this question has been asked before. It would make much more sense to close it for being a duplicate than to close it for being off-topic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [$a\mid b$ if and only if $ac \mid bc$ where $c\neq 0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671660/a-mid-b-if-and-only-if-ac-mid-bc-where-c-neq-0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$bc=(ac)k\iff b=ak$. Of course you can only cancel $c$ if $c$ is different to zero.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: thank you, sorry I am a beginner. Please explain more. so sorry.

Comment: what is your definition for $a|b$?

Comment: what is $k$ in your answer?

Comment: One definition for $a|b$ is there exists an integer $k$  so that $b=ak$. This is the same as saying $\frac{b}{a}=k$ is an integer.

Comment: You really should state explicitly in the *answer* the key role played by one of the hypotheses.

Comment: $c\neq 0$?, so $c$ is invertible?

Comment: Yes, because it fails otherwise. The answer should at least give some hint that the hypothesis is needed.

Answer (score 2):

The expression $ac \mid bc$ means that there exists an integer $n \in \mathbb Z$ such that
$$bc = n(ac).$$

Since $c \neq 0$
$$b = na \iff a \mid b.$$