# There are natural numbers $a,b,c$ such that $ac\mid bc$, while $a\nmid b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> There are natural numbers $a,b,c$ such that $ac\mid bc$, while $a\nmid b$.

My answer was False. I substituted numbers for $a,b,c$. But I think I have confused my self. so $a = 2 , b = 4 , c = 6$.

Comment: Yes, you are confused! If you have a valid counterexample, then you can't possibly prove it. What was your counterexample?

Comment: Also, if you're trying to prove it,  you need to show it's true for all possible values of the variables (as long as they satisfy he hypothesis), so trying examples won't get you a proof (although it may show you _why_ it's true).

Comment: But here's a hint:
If $u|v$ and $u$ is nonzero then what can you say about the fraction $v/u$? Conversely, if $v/u$ is [what kind of number] then $u|v$.

Comment: haha yeah I don't have a counter example but I'm not sure how to prove it

Comment: but in my example its a not | b  so wouldn't that make it different

Comment: Alternatively, use the algebraic _definition_ of $u|v$. Do you know it? If not, look it up.

Comment: whats the mathematical term of the | sign

Comment: Try some numbers where $ac|bc$. For the numbers tested, What about the truth of $a|b$?

Comment: a|b is possible. But a not |b is not possible

Comment: The notation $u|v$ means u,v are integers an u divides v.

Comment: Right. a|b follows from ac|bc. That's what you have to prove.

Comment: Do you have an algebraic definition for $u|v$?

Comment: given two integers a and b, we say that a divides b if there is an integer c such that b = ac

Comment: Right, except don't use c for this problem, since c is in use. Use x or some other letter.

Comment: So if ac|bc then ?? = ?? times ??. Then do some algebra. There's one awkward case, which I guess you have to worry about, but worry about it when it shows up. That sporadic case can definitely interfere with the actual answer, but find the general truth first.

Comment: By the way -- I read the question too quickly, For the question, as stated, a single counterexample proves that the statement is false, so there was no need for any kind of general proof. But what you're asking is how to show the statement is _always_ false (or at least almost always).

Comment: The one worry will be the case c = 0. Other than that case, the algebraic definition quickly leads to a proof that ac|bc implies a|b.

Comment: As I remarked below, it is true $\iff 0\in \Bbb N,\,$ so you need to say if your definition of "natural number" includes $0,\ \ $ Both possibilities are in wide use, so we cannot infer which you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$a\mid b$ if and only if $ac \mid bc$ where $c\neq 0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671660/a-mid-b-if-and-only-if-ac-mid-bc-where-c-neq-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed that $\Bbb N=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$.

**Given Statement:** $\exists a,b,c\in\Bbb N$ ; $ac|bc\implies a\not|\ \ b$

**Negation Statement:** $\forall a,b,c\in\Bbb N$, $ac|bc\implies a|b$.

Which of the two statements is true?

We claim that the negation statement is true.

Let   $a,b,c\in\Bbb N$ such that $ab|bc$. Then $$\frac{b}{a}=\frac{bc}{ac}\in\Bbb N.$$ This means that $a|b$.

Because the negation statement is true, what can be said to the given statement? The answer is FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

The statement $ac|bc$ means $ack = bc$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore $ak = b$, or equivalently $a|b$. So the original statement is not true.

Edit: it has been pointed out that if either $a$ or $b$ is 0 then the statement is trivially true.

Comment: yeah it's not true because you can't do a not |b

Comment: You can't cancel $c$ if $c=0$. If $0$ is considered natural, then it is true:  $0a\mid 0b$ but this doesn't imply $a\mid b,\,$ e.g. $\,a,b = 2,1.\ \ $